# Delete with referential constraint in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have developed and deployed web application for Employee Appraisal with ASP.net MVC 4 
and EF 6 with code First.

To make it simple we have Project, Member and Feedback.

Project and Member has One to Many relationship.

Member and Feedback has one to one relationship.

The weirdest thing I found while fixing the DeleteMember method

```
public bool DeleteMember(int id)
{
    var member = this.context.Member.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    this.context.Member.Remove(member);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

will give the error  `The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint ...` in my method

when I add a line

```
var feedback = this.context.Feedback.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Member.Id == Member.Id);
```

after the line

```
var member = this.context.Member.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

It deleted the Member as well as Feedback without any error. Now my question is what changes I made so that referential constraint error is now stop throwing now. Is this bug with EF?

FYI, I am not using `Fluent API`.

Comment: You might have to define CascadeOnDelete() in the OnModelBuilding-Event.

Comment: Alternatively include Feedback on Loading the member

Comment: It makes sense if we include feedback in Member and deletion work. But my question is I have not include the feedback in the Member and it is deleting as expected without any error. but how and why?

Comment: You load it? So it is available for the context.

Comment: But Ignoring the check for constraint violation and deletion of associated object does not make sense while i am loading to another variable

Comment: It makes totally sense, since the context loads it and attaches it.